# Spring boot doesn't identify html templates without Thymeleaf dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring-boot 2.5.0 and maven as dependency management tool. I have following dependencies as of now in my project.

```
"<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>"
```

I want to use jsp instead of thymeleaf but when I put my "index.html" file inside *templates* or *static* sub-folder of *resources* folder it doesn't recognize the html file and throws white label error.When I added the thymeleaf dependency it worked perfectly and recognized the html file. **So, what should I do to make spring-boot detect my html file without adding thymeleaf dependency.** By the way I have never used jsp before.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re doing with html files and JSP - you’ll have to provide specific details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: see this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-with-jsp-view) may be useful

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am practicing and just creating a view in the browser. While practicing I am using an html file which simply says hello. I am planning to change it later on with a jsp file but this is not the problem. The problem is my file is not getting detected. Does it even matter either it's jsp or html file? I am just asking for my view to be detected.

Comment: Just a sidenote: If you just started you should definately go with thymeleaf. It‘s much cleaner than jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing either of the two things.

1. you should put below the property with the desired value in the property/yaml file

   spring.mvc.view.prefix: <location of html/jsp> 
   spring.mvc.view.suffix: <.extension>
2. check at your controller whether you are sending the correct view name or not.

Comment: Thankyou Nishant
I found out spring itself won't detect any html files without any template engine like thymeleaf. We should either add thymeleaf dependency or use jsp as shown in this site
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/